# Removing non-ascii characters from any given stringtype in Python

Tags: python, string, unicode, replace, non-ascii-characters

```
>>> teststring = 'aõ'
>>> type(teststring)
<type 'str'>
>>> teststring
'a\xf5'
>>> print teststring
aõ
>>> teststring.decode("ascii", "ignore")
u'a'
>>> teststring.decode("ascii", "ignore").encode("ascii")
'a'
```

which is what i really wanted it to store internally as i remove non-ascii characters. Why did the decode("ascii give out a unicode string ?

```
>>> teststringUni = u'aõ'
>>> type(teststringUni)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> print teststringUni
aõ
>>> teststringUni.decode("ascii" , "ignore")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#79>", line 1, in <module>
    teststringUni.decode("ascii" , "ignore")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf5' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> teststringUni.decode("utf-8" , "ignore")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#81>", line 1, in <module>
    teststringUni.decode("utf-8" , "ignore")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf5' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> teststringUni.encode("ascii" , "ignore")
'a'
```

Which is again what i wanted.
I don't understand this behavior. Can someone explain to me what is happening  here?

**edit:** i thought this would me understand things so i could solve my real program problem that i state here:
[Converting Unicode objects with non-ASCII symbols in them into strings objects (in Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669436/converting-unicode-objects-with-non-ascii-symbols-in-them-into-strings-objects-in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple: .encode converts Unicode objects into strings, and .decode converts strings into Unicode.

Comment: if this does not work, also try to use BeautifulSoup(html).encode for html or the regex module

Answer (score 4):

> Why did the decode("ascii") give out a unicode string?

Because that's what `decode` is *for*: it decodes byte strings like your ASCII one into unicode.

In your second example, you're trying to "decode" a string which is already unicode, which has no effect. To print it to your terminal, though, Python must encode it as your default encoding, which is ASCII - but because you haven't done that step explicitly and therefore haven't specified the 'ignore' parameter, it raises the error that it can't encode the non-ASCII characters.

The trick to all of this is remembering that `decode` takes an encoded bytestring and converts it to Unicode, and `encode` does the reverse. It might be easier if you understand that **Unicode is not an encoding**.

Comment: Well, you are right, except for some details. Since he can print `'a\xf5'` correctly, his terminals encoding is not ascii but .. something else. The console encoding is a really common problem, but it's not the case this time. Also, `teststringUni.decode("ascii" , "ignore")` does not fail when you try to print the result. It tells Python that teststringUni is a ascii encoded string (it is clearly unicode, but Python trusts the user) and tries to decode it - which cannot work ofc.

Comment: yes, i think that is the problem: What is my terminal encoding? Just because an object type is string it does not mean the encoding is ascii, i understood that. My problem now is to figure out how i can translate something that has type unicode into the the string type of the terminal, while retaining all information.