# Convert raw byte string to Unicode without knowing the codepage beforehand

Tags: python, windows, unicode, rawbytestring

When using the right-click menu context, windows passes file path as raw (byte) string type.

For example:

```
path = 'C:\\MyDir\\\x99\x8c\x85\x8d.mp3'
```

Many external packages in my application are expecting `unicode` type strings, so I have to convert it into `unicode`.

That would be easy if we'd known the raw string's encoding beforehand (In the example, it is `cp1255`). However I can't know which encoding will be used locally on each computer around the world.

How can I convert the `string` into `unicode`? Perhaps using `win32api` is needed?

Comment: ASCII is a codec that can always be converted to Unicode; just `.decode('ASCII')`. What you mean is not ASCII but encoded bytes.

Comment: You can't in general decode a string to unicode without knowing the encoding.  Your text is not ASCII but some unknown encoding.

Comment: Your example is *not* cp1255, decoding using that codec fails. It is not UTF-16 either, which is suprising as that is what Windows uses internally for filenames.

Comment: Does `import locale; path.decode(locale.getpreferredencoding())` work perhaps?

Comment: Judging by your assertion that this is `cp1255` (hebrew), I tried out a few other codecs; this is actuall `cp856` or `cp862`; both decode the bytes you gave as: `C:\MyDir\שלום.mp3`

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's interesting. `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns `cp1255` on my system.

Comment: @BrenBarn That's right, it's impossible to decode it without the encoding, but windows should know the right encoding.

Comment: @iTayb: If you have cp856 files on a cp1255 system, and no out-of-band way of knowing that they're cp856, there's really nothing you can do. I'm guessing Explorer and the DOS prompt don't show them properly either. For special cases (e.g., everything's probably utf-8, cp1255, or cp856), you can write some "guessing code" that tries various heuristics and usually guesses the charset, but that's the best you could do.

Comment: @iTayb: How do you expect Windows to know the encoding? If your system is set to cp1255, Windows expects all of your files to be cp1255. Unless… I believe it's possible to configure a non-default codepage for each drive or remote share somehow. Could you have a cp856 C: drive on a cp1255 system or something?

Comment: since you don't seem to have a better alternative, maybe use chardet to guess the encoding for you?

Comment: @abarnert Windows itself shows it properly (through `explorer.exe`), so windows somehow knows how to handle it.

Comment: @cmd thanks for that, didnt know that such a package exist.

Comment: what does `path.decode("mbcs")` (ansi codepage) produce? Note: Windows uses Unicode filenames internally; look for a way to get Unicode strings directly instead of decoding bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea why you might be getting the DOS code page (862) instead of ANSI (1255) - how is the right-click option set up?

Either way - if you need to accept any arbitrary Unicode character in your arguments you can't do it from Python 2's `sys.argv`. This list is populated from the bytes returned by the non-Unicode version of the Win32 API (`GetCommandLineA`), and that encoding is never Unicode-safe.

Many other languages including Java and Ruby are in the same boat; the limitation comes from the Microsoft C runtime's implementations of the C standard library functions. To fix it, one would call the Unicode version (`GetCommandLineW`) on Windows instead of relying on the cross-platform standard library. Python 3 does this.

In the meantime for Python 2, you can do it by calling `GetCommandLineW` yourself but it's not especially pretty. You can also use `CommandLineToArgvW` if you want Windows-style parameter splittng. You can do this with `win32` extensions or also just plain `ctypes`.

[Example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/572200-get-sysargv-with-unicode-characters-under-windows/) (though the step of encoding the Unicode string back to UTF-8 bytes is best skipped).

Answer (score 2):

Usually I use own util function for safe conversion from usual codepages to unicode.  For reading default OS encoding probably *locale.getpreferredencoding* function could help (http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding).

Example of util function that tries to converting to unicode by iterating some predefined encodings:

```
# coding: utf-8
def to_unicode(s):
    if isinstance(s, unicode): return s

    from locale import getpreferredencoding
    for cp in (getpreferredencoding(), "cp1255", "cp1250"):
        try:
            return unicode(s, cp)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass
    raise Exception("Conversion to unicode failed")
    # or fallback like:
    # return unicode(s, getpreferredencoding(), "replace")

print (to_unicode("addđšđčćžŽŠĐ"))
```

Fallback could be enabled by using unicode function argument errors="replace". Reference http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode

For converting back to some codepage you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697906/python-unicodeencodeerror-converting-unicode-to-ascii/16698571#16698571).